# Git: error if "No newline at end of file"

Tags: git

One gets a warning in `git diff` if a text file lacks a newline at the end of the file, seems reasonable.  Is there a way to get git to error (on `add` or `commit` say) in this case, just so that I notice (and can fix) the problem earlier?

Comment: Start by configuring your text editor to save files using POSIX semantics (which terminates *every*  line with `\n`), rather than DOS semantics (*separates* lines with `\r\n`).

Comment: This is not actually a warning, but a part of the diff.  If the diff is applied with `git apply`, it will remove the newline from the end of the file.  Without this, it would be impossible to round-trip files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do that in Git would be to use a [pre-commit hook](https://githooks.com/).

You can definitely create a [pre-commit hook in your Git repository to warn you about missing newline at the end of a file](https://gist.github.com/Robotic-Brain/ffafe886a9e4b7b9e946318817440abe), or even have a [pre-commit hook to automatically insert a newline for you](https://gist.github.com/johnjohndoe/4024222).

However, my advice would be to *not* do that, and instead configure your text editor to automatically insert the new line whenever you save the file, which avoids the issue entirely.

Most editors nowadays support settings defined in an [.editorconfig file](https://editorconfig.org/), where you can set `insert_final_newline = true` to have text editors ensure text files will always have a newline.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the pre-commit hook looks the way to go.  Of course, my `.emacs` has a `require-final-newline` directive, but not all files are created by editors, nor by me.

Comment: @jjg Just remember that git-hooks are local to your repository so it's only useful for the files that you create yourself (before you commit)... If you are collaborating with other people and want to catch this issue at the repository level, you should have a build server analyze the files when new commits are added (e.g. TeamCity, Jenkins, Azure Pipelines, GitHub Actions, etc...)